# Do I need to DeleteLocalRef a jstring object returned by JNI call?

Tags: java-native-interface

Suppose I'm using JNI to call some Java method that returns `String`, i. e. `jstring` in native code:

```
jstring jStr = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(myApplicationClass, getString);
```

Do I then need to call `env->DeleteLocalRef(jStr)`? I think I do, but I can't find any specific instructions that state so in the JNI reference, and I can see I have a lot of code that doesn't call it - tried and true code. But if there was a minor memory leak, no one would notice since this code doesn't create many objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every local reference you create is automatically freed when your JNI-called function returns to Java.

The [JNI specification outlines two cases](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242) where you might want to use `DeleteLocalRef`:

> A native method accesses a large Java object, thereby creating a local reference to the Java object. The native method then performs
>   additional computation before returning to the caller. The local
>   reference to the large Java object will prevent the object from being
>   garbage collected, even if the object is no longer used in the
>   remainder of the computation.

In other words, if you allocated a multi-megabyte string and no longer need it, you can delete the reference immediately, instead of leaving it to the JVM when you return to it. However, this is only useful if you need to perform additional steps in the JNI world before returning.

Note that this situations talks about a JNI function that is called **from Java**. 
By attaching native threads to the JVM you can end up in the reverse situation, where your native code calls **into** the JVM. In that situation the JVM will **not** auto-free your local references and you need to delete local references yourself.

As a concrete example of that case, all the local references created in [this function in the JNI cookbook](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipeNo049/c/recipeNo049_main.c#L52-L68) will linger; they are never cleaned up manually.

> A native method creates a large number of local references, although not all of them are used at the same time. Since the VM needs
>   a certain amount of space to keep track of a local reference, creating
>   too many local references may cause the system to run out of memory.
>   For example, a native method loops through a large array of objects,
>   retrieves the elements as local references, and operates on one
>   element at each iteration. After each iteration, the programmer no
>   longer needs the local reference to the array element.

This one is simpler: there is an upper limit to the number of local references.

Comment: you are right, in my sample code (recipeNo049) I explicitly added comment, that memory will leak. This was done for a purpose to minimise the code base. But yes, you are right.

Comment: Oh, it was not meant to point fingers. I just remembered that as a useful example of what I was talking about. Don't feel shamed into adding deletelocalref calls :-)

Comment: No offences taken, no hard feelings ;) I just wanted to make it clear that example is "broken" on purpose ;)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! So, it's not always required to delete local references, but it's never a mistake to do so as soon as the referenced object is no longer needed, right?

Comment: Correct. The only harm is that all the `DeleteLocalRef` calls might start crowding out the useful code.

Comment: There are quite a few C++ wrappers that employ RAII to delete local references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you must dispose the local references returned by Java callbacks. The standard rules apply: instead of DeleteLocalRef(), you can use PushLocalFrame()/PopLocalFrame(), or the local reference will be released automatically when the thread is detached from JVM, or the native method returns to Java (if this happens inside a native method).

Comment: Good remark about the local frames. Too bad that you have to pre-allocate the amount of local references.

Comment: Thanks, I've done a fair share of JNI programming, but never knew/noticed these functions.

Comment: Emphasis on DeleteLocalRef() method here