# Calling DeleteObjectRef when GetObjectField returns jstring

Tags: java-native-interface

When calling **GetObjectField** which returns a **jstring**, do I need to call **DeleteLocalRef** for the **jstring**?

I know I have to do it for returned objects, but I have no clue for **jstrings**.

Comment: A string is an object. However, you only need to call `DeleteLocalRef` if your native function won't return back to Java code, or if it will use so many local references that you might overflow the local reference table. This goes for local references to any kind of Java object, not just strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to DeleteLocalRef a jstring object returned by JNI call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931787/do-i-need-to-deletelocalref-a-jstring-object-returned-by-jni-call)